# How do you update an imported script in the Python interpreter?

Tags: python

I have a script that I am in the process of debugging. I've imported it using:

```
import foo
```

Then I update foo. After I do "import foo" again, nothing is changed. How do I update it without needing to exist the interpreter and reenter? Furthermore, if there are other packages that depend on it, how do I update them to use the newest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `importlib.reload()`. This used to be a builtin (in Python 2), but it doesn't clean up everything. This was considered too confusing and it was moved to importlib for advanced users. Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html?highlight=importlib#importlib.reload) carefully to understand why.

```
>>> import foo
>>> from importlib import reload
>>> # do stuff
>>> reload(foo)
```

Modules in Python are cached in the `sys.modules` dict. They're only loaded from source on the first import. If you delete it there, you can get a similar effect.

The main difference between these two approaches is that `reload()` keeps the same module `__dict__` object (its globals), while just deleting it from `sys.modules` wouldn't. Normally a reload will overwrite these globals with the new definitions if you modify the source. But if you remove a definition in the source, the old version will still be there after a reload. You can actually use this to your advantage in some cases: if you want a resource (like a network connection) to persist over reloads, you can write its initialization to skip the step if the global is already defined.